# Firebase cloud functions threw an error "FunctionsException: INTERNAL" in unity 2022.3.11

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

```
await FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if(task.Result == DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
                auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
                reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
                func = FirebaseFunctions.GetInstance(app,"asia-northeast1");

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(task.Result.ToString());
                return;
            }
        });
```

Firebase was initialized as described above.　And I wrote a code like this.

```
await func.GetHttpsCallable("createSessionCookie").CallAsync(idToken).ContinueWith(task =>{
            if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            {
                return task.Result.Data.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(task.Result.Data.ToString());
                return "";
            }
        });
```

But the error "FunctionsException: INTERNAL" has happened.

What makes this error?

First, functions registered in Cloud functions were modified to support onCall.

```
import functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import express from 'express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import cors from 'cors';

const functions_address = functions.region('asia-northeast1');

const app = express();
//app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.post("/",cors(), async (req) => {
    const idToken = req.data.idToken;
    const expiresIn = 60 * 5 * 1000; 
  
    try {
      const sessionCookie = await admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn });
    
      return {sessionCookie};
    } catch (error) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', error + 'failed to make sessionCookie');
    }
  });
export const createSessionCookie = functions_address.https.onCall(app);
```

Perhaps this could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When using [HTTPS Event Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) or want to use express, you should define your function using `onRequest`. This type of Cloud Function calls your callback with two arguments - `req` (an [express `Request` object](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req)) and `res` (an [express `Response` object](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res)).

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // your code here
})
```

```
const app = express();

// add routes to app

exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest(app); // calls your app's routes
```

---

When using [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and want Firebase to handle CORS/authentication for you, you should define your function using `onCall`. This type of Cloud Function calls your callback with two arguments - `data` (whatever data you provided from your client-side apps) and `context` (a [`CallableContext` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.https.callablecontext)).

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // your code here
})
```

---

Your problem stems from using a mix of code from each Cloud Function type. As you are using `func.GetHttpsCallable("createSessionCookie")` in the client side code, you should use the latter function type.

```
// client
await func.GetHttpsCallable("createSessionCookie")
  .CallAsync(idToken)
  .ContinueWith(task => {
    if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
      return task.Result.Data.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
      Debug.Log(task.Result.Data.ToString());
      return ""; // null would be a better choice
    }
  });
```

```
// cloud function
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp(); // don't forget to initialize the admin SDK

const functions_address = functions.region('asia-northeast1');
const DURATION_5MINS_MS = 60 * 5 * 1000; 

exports.createSessionCookie = functions_address.https.onCall(async (idToken, context) => {
  const sessionCookie = await admin.auth()
    .createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn: DURATION_5MINS_MS });

  return { sessionCookie };
})
```

Comment: Thank you. The code worked. idToken is just a string and {sessionCookie} is also returned as a string?